# DeleteStopwords in other languages?

Tags: list-manipulation, text

I saw that in new version of *Mathematica* there is an interesting function: `DeleteStopwords` that deletes stopwords from a list of words, but this function is only for the English language. But I'm Italian and my "stopwords" are different from English ones. So I'm wondering if there is a method to create a personal stopwords, and delete a text from it.
This is my code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
mytext = Import["https://gallery.mailchimp.com/66b77b8f219a30e5da628b18b/files/ps.txt"];
WordCloud[mytext]
```

[image]

As you can see there are a lot of word that are stopwords.

Another ideas is to cut all words with length less than three.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You may have to roll your own. You can find lists of stop words for Italian on the web (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/stop-words/ and import them to Mathematica. Then you might use `TextWords` to get a list of words from your text, and `Complement[yourwordlist, stopwordlist]` to get a cleaned list to feed to `WordCloud`. Unfortunately I'm on a tablet at the moment and can't actually do it myself...

Comment: Here is a Github variant of a stopword collection, see https://github.com/stopwords-iso

Answer (score 6):

I use:

```
RemoveStopWords[doc_, stopWords_] := 
  StringDelete[doc, 
   WordBoundary ~~ Alternatives @@ stopWords ~~ WordBoundary, 
   IgnoreCase -> True];
```

Where stopWords is a list of all stop words, I found a list of stop words for my language easily through an internet search.

In addition to this I also remove words that are too short. Another option is to use a method that puts less weight on common words, have a look at [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) for example:

> tf–idf can be successfully used for stop-words filtering in various subject fields including text summarization and classification.

You could essentially use it to figure out what words should be considered stop words. But you'd need more than one document for sure, so it depends on what data you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

> Another ideas is to cut all words with length less than three. Any ideas?

```
StringReplace[mytext, 
 WordBoundary ~~ Repeated[WordCharacter, 2] ~~ WordBoundary -> ""]
```

But I suppose *less or equal three* would be better. Put there `3` then and:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question and very interesting answers. 
I tried to evaluate the answer of Kuba using the MarcoB suggestions.
For instance:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
mytext = Import[
"https://gallery.mailchimp.com/66b77b8f219a30e5da628b18b/files/ps.\
txt"];
stopwordit = 
Import["https://sites.google.com/site/kevinbouge/stopwords-lists/\
stopwords_it.txt?attredirects=0&d=1", {"Text"}];
WordCloud[mytext]
```

[image]

Then I used the kuba function:

```
RemoveStopWords[doc_, stopWords_] := 
StringDelete[doc, 
WordBoundary ~~ Alternatives @@ stopWords ~~ WordBoundary, 
IgnoreCase -> True];
textwithoutSW = RemoveStopWords[mytext, stopwordit];
WordCloud[textwithoutSW]
```

[image]

but the WordClouds are the same, although the word "che" is on the StopWords in Italian language.
What's wrong?

Comment: You don't import the stop words properly, try "List" or "Table" instead: stopwordit = 
  Import["https://sites.google.com/site/kevinbouge/stopwords-lists/\
stopwords_it.txt?attredirects=0&d=1", "List"]; (And that's not from Kuba's post!)